# Set optional constructor value if undefined

Tags: typescript

If I have a class:

```
class MyClass {

  constructor(props?: any) {
    ...
  }
}
```

How would I check if `props?.my_val` is undefined and set a value for it if that is the case?

Comment: I recommend **not** mutating function arguments, but if you insist `props.my_val ??= whatever` which is to say use the [nullish coalescing assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment). Note that in your case *props itself* might be missing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript object properties - create property if not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34419057/javascript-object-properties-create-property-if-not-exist)

Comment: Please add an `new MyClass(???)` and constructor body example how you imagine it to be

Comment: @JaredSmith thanks. I can work with that if I do a check for props existence first. :)